# Testing Wildcard paths

Tags: wildcard, azure-data-factory

I've found a few links that show me how to use wildcard paths in ADF.
This is useful as I have a partition structure I need to read in many different ways.

Is there any way in which to return your query result for checking? like if you were using the GetData activity?

So I could just put in something like 'JobTest/SoftwareV1/2019/1?/**' which returns ALL descendants of 2019 months (10-12)

I just want to run this code and test all the functions I'm reading then use them to query my blob

I have thousands of files going back years so I just want to return the potential paths if you know what I mean

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the results of `Get Metadata` activity to `Set variable` activity.

**Source**:

[image]

1. Pass the output Get Metadata **childitems** in the value of Set variable.

[image]

2. You see all the folders available under my directory.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to list all the files in the BLOB? If so, try this.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51145124/how-to-list-all-blobs-inside-of-a-specific-subdirectory-in-azure-cloud-storage-u